# Как прочитать файл через python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть файл `api.php`, но не могу его прочитать, я таким способом пытался открыть.

```
f = open("api.php", "r")
t = f.read()
print(t)
```

Пытался загуглить но нечего не помогло.

Ошибка

```
"C:\Users\Marlin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\encodings\cp1251.py",
 line 23, in decode return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)
[0] UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 3656: 
character maps to <undefined> 
Для продолжения нажмите любую клавишу . . .
```

Comment: В каком месте, кроме расширения файла, Вы здесь увидели php?

Comment: Скорее всего вы указываете неправильный путь к файлу, который пытаетесь открыть.

Comment: Выложите расположение файла api.php и вашего скрипта

Comment: а что именно пытался загуглить? И что именно не помогло? И что происходит, когда запускаешь свой код?

Comment: Ошибка:           Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Mysor\mysor\работа\parser_directlot_v2\dir_v2.py", line 11, in <module>
    t = f.read()
  File "C:\Users\Marlin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\encodings\cp1251.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 3656: character maps to <undefined>
Для продолжения нажмите любую клавишу . . .

Answer (score 2):

```py
import os
path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "api.php")
f = open(path, "r")
t = f.read()
f.close()
print(t)
```

Когда вы пишете относительный путь к файлу, он ищется в текущей рабочей директории, которая может отличаться от расположения скрипта. Текущую рабочуюю директорию (current working directory) можно получить с помощью `os.getcwd()`, полный путь к скрипту хранится в переменной `__file__`.

Файлы лучше открывать с помощью менеджера контекста with, который гарантирует закрытие файла в случае возникновения исключения и избавляет от необходимости закрывать файл.

```py
import os
path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "api.php")
with open(path, "r") as f
    t = f.read()
print(t)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Если хотите из любого другого места читать, тогда надо указывать абсолютный путь к читаемому файлу.
2. Если просто указываете имя и расширение читаемого файла, тогда файл скрипта и читаемого файла д/б в одном каталоге:
   [image: Расположение файлов]